# facebook : extended token expires on logout

Tags: facebook, token

I am attempting to extend a user token, using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

as suggested in fb docs https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

While this does create a new token, the token is short lived and expires on user log out.

so what am i missing?

i have changed to deprecate the old method setting as suggest as well

Comment: I have decided this problem is wide spread, and an ongoing issue at facebook. they have extended the change for this. i have now enabled the setting for remove offline access permission, and am calling getExtendedAccessToken() function talked about elsewhere. It seems to work now. I think i had accidentally been grabbing the wrong client code.